# AS3 Text Display Problems

Tags: actionscript-3, text, textfield

I've been trying to get this to work for hours and I've looked it up online and followed the examples, but in the end I get a blank screen with every method I find. I am trying to make a 15x15 grid of random letters, but nothing happens and there are no errors or warnings when I compile. Here is the code:

```
    package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.*;

    public class WordSearch extends MovieClip {

        var startX:uint = 0;
        var startY:uint = 0;

        var randomletter:uint = (Math.random() * 26);
        var letter:TextField = new TextField();

        public function WordSearch(){

        letter = new TextField();

        for ( var row:uint = 0; row < 15; row++ )
        {

            for ( var column:int = 0; column < 15; column++ )
            {
                switch(randomletter)
                {
                    case 1:
                        letter.text = "%";
                        letter.x = startX;
                        letter.y = startY;
                        addChild(letter);
                }
                startX = startX + 16
            }

            startX = 0
            startY = startY + 16
             }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the WordSearch to the stage?

```
var ws:WordSearch = new WordSearch();
stage.addChild(ws);
```

The code you posted doesn't add anything to the stage so it won't display anything.

Comment: Thanks I think that did it. Except now all of the letters are the same letter instead of random letters (I added at least 3 more cases with the addchild in them but it still is only one showing up)

Comment: You need to put var `randomletter:uint = (Math.random() * 26);` inside the for loop before the switch.

Comment: If this did solve the issue, please mark this answer as the solution.